# Selenium from Python: How to Select from a Dropdown Table

Tags: selenium

I am trying to teach myself some basic Selenium so that I can teach it to my students. I am trying to get some data from an Audubon page. This code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://netapp.audubon.org/CBCObservation/Historical/ResultsBySpecies.aspx?1&1"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
enter_common = browser.find_element_by_id("txtCommon")
enter_common.send_keys("kestrel")
checkbox = browser.find_element_by_id("gridSpecies_DXSelBtn0")
checkbox.click()
```

gets me through Step 1. Then I am stuck. I have tried everything I can think of to do Step 2. Here is an image:

[image]

When I click in the Start Year box, a dropdown appears that I can use to select a year. However, as far as I can tell, it is a table element, not a select element. I can't seem to directly send_keys to the input field, nor can I select a row from the table. I can't even get the text back out of it:

```
y1960 = browser.find_element_by_id("cmbStartYear_DDD_L_LBI59T0")
y1960.text
''
```

I'm over my head, thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example clicking the td with text 115 tag. Just added an example of using webdriver wait if you want to switch over since it stabilizes finding elements.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
browser.get('https://netapp.audubon.org/CBCObservation/Historical/ResultsBySpecies.aspx?1&1')
enter_common = browser.find_element_by_id("txtCommon")
enter_common.send_keys("kestrel")
checkbox = browser.find_element_by_id("cmbStartYear_I")
checkbox.click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//td[@class='dxeListBoxItem GridEditDropDown dxeFTM' and .='115']"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I am getting, which is what I was getting with what I posted above: ElementNotInteractableExceptionTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-7a6dd950abb2> in <module>
----> 1 wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//td[@class='dxeListBoxItem GridEditDropDown dxeFTM' and .='115']"))).click()

Comment: did you change the checkbox.

Comment: Nope!! That got me one step farther. Now I have a timeout exception. I'll keep messing with it. Thanks!

Comment: I used '61' and got the value out in your case.

Comment: My key takeaway from this experience is that I need to recreate every single action I take when surfing a site manually in selenium. Can't miss one click.